# Error when Deploying Java app with GlassFish

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish

What does this error with GlassFish (when being used with Eclipse) mean? login is a Java project I was working with earlier. I take it I have to stop it or remove it or something. Can some please help?

```
cannot Deploy numberquiz
deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : 
java.lang.Exception: WEB0113: Virtual server [server] already has a web module [login] loaded at 
[/numberquiz]; therefore web module [numberquiz] cannot be loaded at this context path on this 
virtual server. . Please see server.log for more details.
```

Thanks, Conor.

Comment: You cannot have two wars with the same context path. The context path has to be unique or the server will get confused when you try to access a resource. Either change the context path of one of them or remove it from the server.

Comment: I am extremely new to all of this. Where is the context path set and, just so that I know for the future, how do you remove a war from the server? Thanks.

Comment: if you have deployed it as a war file it is usually set on the `deployment screen`. If you are deploying as a EAR file it will be in the `application.xml` under `context-root`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You already have an application deployed with the contextpath `/numberquiz`. Changing the context path in your project settings will result in the same problem the next time you deploy your app.

You have to undeploy your application via Eclipse or in the Glassfish Admin GUI,

The Admin GUI can be accessed under `http://localhost:4848`. Go to `Applications` in the left menu, select your application and click `Undeploy`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is because you are trying to deploy an application in GlassFish that is conflicting with another application with the same "Context Root". You have to undeploy the application in GlassFish or alter the Context Root of either of the applications.
In Glassfish 5, open your browser and go to the url- localhost:4848 it will open the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition index.jsf page. On the left panel click on the Applications drop-down and select the application whose Context Root is conflicting with the new application. The Edit Application pane opens on the right, then you can now alter the Context Root. After this, click the save button on the top-right corner.